# Ionic view http get works on ios but not on android

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework

My app works on Ionic view on iOS and when I run it directly on Android using `ionic cordova run android`, but it doesn't work on Ionic View app on Android. I put in place the monitoring using Ionic Pro and I don't understand the error message:

```
Error:
at ? (main.js:101:82)
at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3:14976)
at Object.onInvoke (vendor.js:5123:33)
at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3:14916)
at r.run (polyfills.js:3:10143)
at ? (polyfills.js:3:20242)
at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3:15660)
at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js:5114:33)
at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3:15581)
at r.runTask (polyfills.js:3:10834)
```

Comment: Nothing useful in this error message. Do you see anything in console? (You can use chrome inspect to see the console while running on Android) https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: I think Ionic view doesn't use WebView because I don't see anithing with the devtool.